# Push-Pull voltage-to-current converter

Tags: operational-amplifier, power-amplifier, transconductance

How to make the following voltage-to-current converter bidirectional, so that it maintains the requested current through the load, even when that load stores energy and attempts to oppose the reduction of the current flowing through it?

[image]

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is a two quadrant constant current source.

Comment: @winny: Perhaps even a two-quadrant Transconductance Amplifier.

Comment: If the load stores energy and attempts to oppose the reduction of the current flowing through it, you need additional free-wheeling or recovery diodes.

Comment: @Uwe:  I tried that. Free-wheeling diodes help to maintain the current in the load longer.  They do not help in reducing that current faster, i.e. follow the input faster.

Comment: If you to reduce the load current faster, you may try a diode and a damping resistor in series. Have a look at https://archive.ph/20130112153214/http://www.dprg.org/tutorials/1998-04a/ especially about the forward, reverse, brake and fuse test conditions.

Comment: I don't see a problem.  The opamp maintains the programmed current through R1 no matter where it comes from.  If the load is an inductor, its impedance is initially high (and the opamp increases drive to Q1 to increase the current in R1 until the loop closes), and then settles down to the inductor's resistance at steady state (and the opamp decreases drive to Q1 to increase its resistance to compensate for the lower load impedance.  A step decrease in the source causes the load to partially discharge, increasing the current through R1, and the opamp modulates Q1 to compensate.

Comment: What load do you exactly have in mind? You claim that you need more than 1 quadrant of operation: which quadrants do you need on a load current-vs-load voltage graph? **Without knowing this you essentially don’t know what you need and the question is unanswerable**. The schematic you show is quadrant 1 source: positive voltage and positive current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mean to make it bidirectional.

You mean that it should maintain the current independent of the polarity of the voltage across the load.

If the load is storing energy the voltage will be such that the drain of Q1 is lower in voltage than the supply. That is the drain is negative relative the the supply.

If the load is sourcing energy the voltage across the load will be of the opposite polarity such that the voltage at the drain is higher than the 30V supply. That is the drain is positive relative the the supply.

The circuit shown can already do that provided the voltage and power rating of the MOSFET is adequate.

Comment: OK, I will make another question how to make it bidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

When the current is increasing you may need more supply voltage than 30V to control the current to the desired level at the desired rate of change.

When the current is decreasing the voltage at the drain may increase beyond the rail so the MOSFET needs to have adequate voltage and safe operating area ratings. You may need something like a series zener + diode to protect the MOSFET from rapid decreases in the control input.

Remember, the voltage across the inductance will be L*di/dt, and that’s on top of the voltage across the resistance in the load. So to get arbitrarily high rates of change in a load that is a series L+R you need arbitrarily high voltages.